# Hibernate: update to sum from other table

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to replicate this query from MySQL to HQL:
*UPDATE users u, mines m SET u.mana = u.mana + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(m.mana_rate) FROM mines m WHERE m.user_id = u.id), 0)*

Simply doing this in HQL:
*update User u set u.mana = u.mana + (select coalesce(sum(m.manaRate), 0) from Mine m where m.userId = u.id)*

Gives following error:
*Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: query [update mm.user.User u set u.mana = u.mana + (select coalesce(sum(m.manaRate), 0) from mm.map.buildings.mines.Mine m where m.userId = u.id)]*

I'm new to Hibernate, so I don't really know where to start, and what the error means.
If it's not possible, can i write a native MySQL query in Hibernate?

EDIT: The problem seems to be in "u.mana = u.mana +", because when I just do u.mana = (select... the query works just fine

Comment: I have also experienced weird behavior executing bulk deletes involving subqueries, and at the end used native SQL instead. It seems like a problem of the HQL parser.

Answer (score 1):

you can write native queries in hibernate, more about that [here](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/entitymanager/reference/en/html/query_native.html). bit sure what is wrong with your query though.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty simple, using createSQLQuery() :)